# does it matter whether I have one if clause between many else if?

Tags: java, if-statement

I just found one thing that bothers me and left me puzzled:

I have a method that looks like this:

```
if( condition1){}

else if(....){}

if(){} // this is confusing, does it matter if it becomes else if? 
       //Would the behavior change?

else if(){}
else if(){}
```

Comment: yes now you have 2 ifelse blocks

Comment: @FastSnail, please explain , all if statements are equal to each other, they are not nested into one another, do they become nested?

Comment: you should debug and check the behavior

Comment: U should debug this programm and see where the computer goes than u see the difference

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course it matters. An `else if` condition is only evaluated if all the preceding if and else-if conditions of the same if-else-if block were false.

An `if` condition will always be evaluated, since it starts a new if-else-if block.

You should choose between the two based on the required logic.

```
if( condition1){}

else if(....){} // this condition is only evaluated if all the preceding 
                // conditions were false

if(){} // this condition will be evaluated regardless of the result of 
       // evaluation the preceding conditions

else if(){}
else if(){}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if(condition1)
.
.
else if(....){}
```

after else if(), if you add  if (condition ..)  statement then it will be considered separate if else block .

Answer (score 1):

If your third if becomes else-if, it will be evaluated only when the first if-else if is false

If you leave it like that, it will be evaluated regardless whether the first if-else if is true or false

Answer (score 1):

`if else if` blocks acts like `switch` blocks with one difference, As switch directly jump to the code block which matches the input case where as `if else if` block has to reach each condition to reach a particular code block.

Inserting another `if{}` block between a chain of `if else if` will simply create a new chain of `if else if` block from your newly inserted `if` blocks.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, it does matter. But in case it helps, let me point out an important fact: there's no such thing as `else if`!

An `else` keyword is followed by a single statement. There are [lots of kinds of statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5): method invocations, value assignments... and blocks.

```
if (condition1)
  doSomething();
else
  doSomethingElse(); // a method invocation statement

// or...

if (condition2)
  doSomething();
else { // a block statement, which itself contains statements
  soSomethingElse();
  andAnotherThing();
}
```

This should all look familiar, but consider that [an `if-else` is itself a statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9):

```
// *all* of this is just a single statement, the if-else statement
if (condition3) {
   doYetAnotherThing();
} else {
   doEvenAnotherThing();
}
```

Putting this all together, an `else if` is really just an `else` whose statement is itself an `if-else`. The following are *exactly* equivalent:

```
// the syntax you're used to:
if (condition1) {
   doSomething();
} else if (condition2) {
   doAnotherThing();
} else {
   doAThirdThing();
}

// the same exact thing, written slightly more verbosely:
if (condition1) {
   doSomething();
} else {
  if (condition2) { // note that this if-else is within the else{...}
    doAnotherThing();
  } else {
    doAThirdThing();
  }
}
```

And *that's* really why the "plain" `if` in the middle of your stream of `else-if`s starts a new line of questioning. Without the `else` in front of it, the previous `if` is just a plain `if`, not an `if-else` -- and thus that "nesting" doesn't happen.

Taking that last example I posted, and removing the `else` from before the `if (condition2)`, we'd get:

```
if (condition1) {
   doSomething();
} /*else*/ if (condition2) {
   doAnotherThing();
} else {
   doAThirdThing();
}
```

Note that without that `else` to next the `else if(condition2)`, this is really what it looks like, and nothing more. Now all we need is to use slightly different formatting, and the logic becomes clear:

```
if (condition1) {
   doSomething();
}
if (condition2) {
   doAnotherThing();
} else {
   doAThirdThing();
}
```